# How to create a new table by comparing table a to table b records?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables Table A and Table B compare each field and create a Table C that converts the numbers to the mapped color

Table A contains:

```
n1 n2 n3 n4   
10 40 16 30    
30 40 16 10
```

Table B contains:

```
Red Blue    
10   16   
40   30
```

**Updated Table B per @Strawberry advice contains:**

```
n_val color    
10   red   
40   red
16   blue
30   blue
```

I want Table C to be outputted like this:

```
n1   n2  n3   n4    
Red  Red Blue Blue   
Blue Red Blue Red
```

How do I go about doing this in SQL

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Perfect comment @AlbertoMoro

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of a poorly designed schema

Comment: Actually, @Strawberry, I think this kind of problem is symptomatic of a SQL instructor trying to come up with their own "clever" version of FizzBuzz.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a weird query but it delivers the expected result

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN n1 IN (SELECT Red FROM tableB) THEN 'Red' ELSE 'Blue' END as n1,
   CASE WHEN n2 IN (SELECT Red FROM tableB) THEN 'Red' ELSE 'Blue' END as n2,
   CASE WHEN n3 IN (SELECT Red FROM tableB) THEN 'Red' ELSE 'Blue' END as n3,
   CASE WHEN n4 IN (SELECT Red FROM tableB) THEN 'Red' ELSE 'Blue' END as n4
FROM tableA
```

Comment: Joakim I've taken the advice from @Strawberry and adjusted table_b as suggested and kept table_a as is as it is the raw data. I've tried using your query but not successful, how do I adjust it so I pick the value in color column instead of 'Red' & 'Blue'

Comment: @Tony.C I don't see why I need to update my answer because of this since it isn't much of an improvement. To get a better solution you need to modify both tables, not just one

Comment: Joakim If I'm able to take the value from the color column then it would be a much more scalable solution as I would not need to add a new color to the query each time I need a new color.

Answer (score 0):

A normalised design might look like this:

table_A

```
id  n n_val
101 1 10  
102 1 30 

101 2 40 
102 2 40 

101 3 16 
102 3 16

101 4 30   
102 4 10
```

table_B

```
n_val colour
   10 red
   16 blue
   30 blue
   40 red
```

Comment: This is a criticism about his data, not an answer to his question

Comment: @vlemaistre I would argue that it is an answer; in fact the only answer: Either respect the principles of normalised design, or don't bother with an RDBMS. I note from comments that the OP has (partially) redesigned their tables accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an unpleasant query which delivers the expected result;

```
select  (select colour from
            (
            select 'red' colour, red id from tableb
            union all 
            select 'blue',blue from tableb
            ) s where s.id = tablea.n1
            ) n1,
            (select colour from
            (
            select 'red' colour, red id from tableb
            union all 
            select 'blue',blue from tableb
            ) s where s.id = tablea.n2
            ) n2,
                        (select colour from
            (
            select 'red' colour, red id from tableb
            union all 
            select 'blue',blue from tableb
            ) s where s.id = tablea.n3
            ) n3,
                        (select colour from
            (
            select 'red' colour, red id from tableb
            union all 
            select 'blue',blue from tableb
            ) s where s.id = tablea.n4
            ) n4
from tablea;

+------+------+------+------+
| n1   | n2   | n3   | n4   |
+------+------+------+------+
| red  | red  | blue | blue |
| blue | red  | blue | red  |
+------+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Sometimes the cure is worse than the disease